# Directory look up for .mdf failed with operation system error 3 (the system cant find the specified path(microsoft.sqlServer.Express.smo)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have taken SQL backup(.bak) from Windows server 2003 machine and trying to restore in Windows 7. when i am trying to do i have "Directory look up for .mdf failed with operation system error 3 (the system cant find the specified path(microsoft.sqlServer.Express.smo)" message.

I understand that it's trying to find out the path '.MDF' which is not available in this machine (Windows 7). so how i can restore this database.

Answer (score 3):

This manual available also [HERE](http://www.note.id.lv/2016/02/mssql-lookup-mdf-failed.html)

Perform backup restore using T-SQL:

```
RESTORE DATABASE LNE FROM DISK = 'C:\LNE-22012016.bak'
WITH MOVE 'LNE' TO 'C:\SQL_data\LNE.mdf',
MOVE 'LNE_log' TO 'C:\SQL_data\LNE.ldf';
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the restore dialog, go to options and change the path of the file under `Restore As` to a valid path.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply!! i try to do it and ended up with below error                   Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot open backup device 'E:\SQL\Backup_full.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: That error means your backup file is not where you think it is

Comment: yes!!!, i took backup in 2003 server and trying to restore in Window 7 operating system.

Comment: Where is the backup file located on the Windows 7 Machine?